# How find the displaying records count in wpf data grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

if I want to bind 15 records in the wpf data grid, It is showing 15 records without scroll viewer.
if i wnat to bind 20 records in  the wpf data grid , it is showing 15 records with scroll viewer and i have to scroll the scrollbar to view remaining 5 record. This scenario will change depend up on the system screen height. if i run this program in another system which is having large screen height, It will showing 20 records in the data grid without scroll viewer.
So i want to find the count of the records displaying at present in the grid.

Comment: Why do you want to know that? Why do you not just let your view use the space it can get? (i.e. place it in a grid, set the height of the row to something like "5*")

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGrid.Items.Count
```

You can use this.

Hope its helpful.

Comment: if i use this(DataGrid.Items.Count ), I can get all records count from the grid. What exactly i need is, I want to get visible record within the scroll viewer not hiding records  in the scroll viewer.